Deformation retractions from $X$ to subsets $Y$ and $Z$
I'm working on a proof involving deformation retractions of simplicial complexes, but I am unsure about some details involving deformation retractions.
If I have a pair of deformation retractions from $X$ to $Y$ and from $X$ to $Z$, with $Z \subset Y$, does there exist a deformation retraction from $Y$ to $Z$? What about just a homotopy equivalence? Are the answers to these questions different in the context of simplicial complexes?

You can splice - concatenate, multiply,... - your maps at the identity in $X$ for question one - and straight from the definition a deformation retraction is a particular kind of homotopy equivalence.
